# Python Alternative Approaches For Child Processes

Tags: python, background-process, child-process

I am relatively new to Python, I have been tasked with creating a program that will essentially run as a "service" or "daemon".  This process will loop through a set of files and look for new data to process.  If nothing is found the process will sleep for a number of seconds and recheck the files.

If three is a data from a file that needs to be processed, then I would like to start a child process to handle that specific file and the data to be processed.  If there is another file with data to process start another child process for as many files as have data.  Once the children have been started the parent would sleep and recheck for new data.

I Have seen a number of ways that child processes can be initiated:
subprocess.POpen()
Through the threading and multiprocessing modules
Using fork()

I am implementing this in Python 3

Is there a recommended approach for a program of this type?

I have looked for a relatively minimal example here and via Google and am more confused as to an appropriate approach.

Any insights or input would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: try setting a cronjob that runs every few seconds that calls your python script.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to solve your problem, and usually the best approach is the one performant enough for your usecase and simple enough for you to manage.

If you want to use another python script, you could potentially use something like multiprocessing, although there is a lot of overhead involved in using multiprocessing, and it can be slower if the task you're doing isn't CPU intensive, just takes a long time, such as network or disk IO. In IO bound cases like that, async or threading may be better for your usecase, async is especially performant for such things, and if you plan to run large quantities of relatively low CPU impact but highly IO bound tasks, async excels in those scenarios. If you need to run some external program to process your code, you probably want to use subprocess. You can also combine these approaches if you want, using async to delegate out to multiprocessing interpreters for CPU bound tasks and standard async for IO bound tasks, and mixing in some threading if you have a task which doesn't support python's async pattern well.

For file monitoring, you can also look into something like [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) for monitoring files in a low impact way, as polling for file system changes is slower than just having the OS wake your process when a relevant change happens.

Here's some references to get you started:

[Async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

[Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

[Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

[Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful answer and information.  I will look through the links provided.  I appreciate your time and input.